# Image inside NavigationLink does not render

Tags: ios, swiftui

Image inside a Navigation link just shows as blue. Tapping the image does navigate us to the destination correctly.

Code:

```
public var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Image("1")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Code:

```
public var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        NavigationLink(destination: Image("2")) {
            Image("1")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While writing up the question, I realized I need to set the rendering mode correctly. The following fixes this issue:

```
public var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        NavigationLink(destination: Image("2")) {
            Image("1")
            .renderingMode(.original)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
        }
    }
}
```